# Datepicker custom options

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Currently working on a datepicker. The picture below shows the different options available within the datepicker. I was wondering whether there was any way to get rid of the `Today` and `Last 7 days` rows from the datepicker.

[image: 1]]

Here is what I have inside my report_datepicker.js file.

```
$(function () {

$('#Loan_Report_TimePeriod_picker').remove();
$('#Loan_datepicker_report').daterangepicker({ arrows: false, id: 'Loan_Report_TimePeriod_picker', earliestDate: new Date(2000, 0, 1), latestDate: new Date() });
$('#Loan_Report_Datepicker_holder').prepend($('#Loan_Report_TimePeriod_picker'));
$('#Loan_Report_TimePeriod_picker').css({ 'width': '700px', 'margin-top': '-1px', 'top': '0', 'left': '170px', 'right': '0' });

});
```

Comment: This seams as some non-standard component. - It would definitelly help to share the name of it - or at least platform: WPF? web?

Comment: Not quite sure as this is an existing datepicker that has been used at work before I started working here. There is a datepicker js which has the datepicker stuff in function. I'll add it to the code above.

Comment: from what i've asked my colleagues, it seems that the current datepicker is a standard c# datepicker.

Comment: Hmmm...looks bootstrappy.  http://www.daterangepicker.com/#ex4

Comment: just hide those options in CSS for the win

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be using the Date Range Picker library found [here](http://www.daterangepicker.com/).

[Here](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#ex4) is the section about configuring predefined ranges.

I'm not seeing the configuration in the code you pasted, so the app may be setting the options elsewhere.

Comment: Ah thanks, so it was a customer Date Picker rather than a standard c# one. Okay i will look into the configs and see if this helps with my issue. Thanks a bunch Chris

Answer (score 0):

According to params you use, it looks like Jomres version of datetime picker - [Source code](https://jomres.trac.cvsdude.com/Jomres_core_v4/browser/jomres/css/jquery-ui-bootstrap/third-party/jQuery-UI-Date-Range-Picker/js/daterangepicker.jQuery.js?rev=2429)

You can try the following:

```
$(function () {
$('#Loan_Report_TimePeriod_picker').remove();
$('#Loan_datepicker_report').daterangepicker(
  { arrows: false,
    id: 'Loan_Report_TimePeriod_picker',
    earliestDate: new Date(2000, 0, 1),
    latestDate: new Date(),
    presetRanges: [
      {text: 'Month to date', dateStart: function(){ return Date.parse('today').moveToFirstDayOfMonth();  }, dateEnd: 'today' },
      {text: 'Year to date', dateStart: function(){ var x= Date.parse('today'); x.setMonth(0); x.setDate(1); return x; }, dateEnd: 'today' },
      {text: 'The previous Month', dateStart: function(){ return Date.parse('1 month ago').moveToFirstDayOfMonth();  }, dateEnd: function(){ return Date.parse('1 month ago').moveToLastDayOfMonth();  } } ] });
$('#Loan_Report_Datepicker_holder').prepend($('#Loan_Report_TimePeriod_picker'));
$('#Loan_Report_TimePeriod_picker').css({ 'width': '700px', 'margin-top': '-1px', 'top': '0', 'left': '170px', 'right': '0' });
});
```